# Extending the Application class in android twice

Tags: android

Is it okay or possible to extend the Application class in android twice and have two childs of it in an application? And also why do we need it & what's the purpose of extending it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it okay or possible to extend the Application class in android twice and have two childs of it in an application?

You can only have one registered `Application` subclass in the `android:name` attribute of the `<application>` element. You are welcome to create as many subclasses of `Application` as you want, but only one will be used. However, you are welcome to have `MyApp` extend `Application`, have `MyOtherApp` extend `MyApp`, and register `MyOtherApp` in the manifest.

> And also why do we need it

Few apps need it. Quoting [the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html), "There is normally no need to subclass Application".

> what's the purpose of extending it?

If you have application logic that needs to be executed every time Android forks a process for you, `Application` is a common place to trigger that logic. For example, most crash logging libraries (e.g., ACRA) have you configure them in an `Application` subclass, so that they can handle crashes from everywhere else in your app, for every one of your processes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This question popped in my mind because i saw two examples; one to check internet connection and the other on how to use the volley library. So according to your answer, does it mean i can merge the Application subclasses in the examples into a single class to use both these examples in my project?

Comment: @Sammie: In principle, sure. I cannot rule out some conflict between those subclasses that would prevent their merger, but OTOH I cannot think of a scenario where that would occur.

Answer (score 1):

You want something like this?

```
MyApp extends Application
MySecondApp extends MyApp
```

This is possible. There are several usecases for this. For example define an Application for your App but override it for a specific build type or product flavor (e.g. debug). Or a custom Application for your (Android) Tests:

```
MyApp extends Application
MyDebugApp extends MyApp
MyTestApp extends MyApp/MyDebugApp
```

Define each Application Class in the according AndroidManifest:

```
MyApp => main package
MyDebugApp => debug package
MyTestApp => androidTest package
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. The reason extend classes is to reuse code written in the parent class and extend its functionality.

Comment: Now I'm pretty sure you can only have one instance of that class per application, so I can't confirm that it's a good idea.